# It is possible to add more options to the user object in Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Using Firebase Authentication I have a bunch of basic properties for the user object:

- displayName
- email
- photoURL

If I want to store other options like gender, location, mobile number can I do it using Firebase Authentication (as part of the user object) in some way or do I need to use another store option for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `user` model in which you can store all the data that you need. The basic properties you can get them from the `Firebase Authentication` and add them to your model, and the others you can set them according to your needs. We call this class, a model class or a POJO (Plain Old Java Object). Using this model you can populate the data storage and also use it between activities. Don't forget to create public `setters` and public `getters` for all your fields and the apropiate constructors.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I understand, but that model will be used to populate the data storage that I will need to use, I can't update the authentication users properties of the object that Firebase Auth use, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You cannot update the authentication users properties.  This is the reason you need to create another class, to hold the basic properties and the other properties that you need. We call this class, a `model class` or a  `POJO` (Plain Old Java Object). Using this model you can populate the data storage and also use it between activities.